# How to search for only a certain file extension for commit?

Tags: gui, filenames, tortoise-hg, hg, commit

I have an ongoing problem using the TortoiseHG Workbench commit window to search for only a certain file type, such as with Python modules.  Often I have tons of .pyc files that I don't want to be displayed in the list and I only want to filter for the .py files.  But the commit window filename filter bar doesn't seem to allow normal filename wildcard searches.  If I type `*.py` then nothing comes up.  I can type `.py` and then all file extensions starting with ".py" come up but this includes ".pyc".  Is the filename filter bar really that useless, or is there some way that I can actually search for only ".py" files to commit and not ".pyc"?  (I was not able to find any TortoiseHG documentation about this search bar.)

Answer (score 4):

While not a direct answer to your question, the proper way to handle this is to add `*.pyc` to your `.hgignore` file - compiled python files should generally not be checked into a source repository (generally, you shouldn't check build artifacts into the source repository, or any files which can be generated from other files in the repository - they should be generated by your build process after a checkout).

After you add `*.pyc` to your ignore list, TortoiseHG and `hg status` will no longer show any untracked `*.pyc` files. (Any files already added to the repository will still show as normal, and you can still manually add a specific file even if it's on the ignore list with `hg add` or TortoiseHG's explorer menu: Right Click -> TortoiseHG -> Add File